# Python traverse a directory recursively and print contact numbers

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, recursion, regex

I am writing a python code to recursively traverse a directory containing only text files and then print the 10 digit Indian phone number and all its variants. I am very new to python and I have written the following code to print the numbers and this code is working fine. I want to know if there is any other better way to do this program so that the code looks better. Right now, I have used 3 nested for loops, I was wondering if I could reduce time complexity a bit. I am a beginner in python.

Contact_finder.py

```
import os, re

class ContactFinder:

    pattern = re.compile('^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$')

    def traverse(self,dir_path):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
            for file in files:
                filename = os.path.join(root, file)
                with open(filename) as fn:
                    for contact in fn:
                        if self.pattern.match(contact):
                            print contact


contact = ContactFinder()
contact.traverse('/home/sinscary/Documents/niki')
```

Please suggest me a better solution than this.

Comment: That regex would benefit from https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE

Comment: "Code" is [not countable](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/209724/97308).

Answer (score 10):

You don't need a class here at all. You only seem to use it as a namespace and for that just importing it from another file would be sufficient.

I would make `pattern` a global constant and give it a better name.

I would put the extracting of the phone numbers into a separate function for readability.

I would make both functions generators and make it the responsibility of the caller to actually print the contact (or do something else with it).

Lastly, I would use a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard to allow importing these functions without executing the traversal.

```
import os, re class

PHONE_NUNBER = re.compile('^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$')

def get_contacts(filename, pattern):
    with open(filename) as fn:
        for contact in fn:
            if pattern.match(contact):
               yield contact

def get_contacts_recursive(dir_path, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for file in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            for contact in get_contacts(filename, pattern):
                yield contact

def main():
    for contact in get_contacts_recursive('/home/sinscary/Documents/niki', PHONE_NUMBER):
        print contact

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 10):

Explain your regex. Most of the actual logic of your code is buried in one long string. Use raw, multiline strings and the [`re.VERBOSE` mode](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) to allow you to include comments on what each part of the pattern matches. You could also simplify it; it seems odd to have both choices in an optional non-capturing group be optional themselves, for example.

Here's one way to rewrite it.

```
CONTACT_NUMBER = re.compile(r'''
    ^  # start of line
    (?:
      (?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?  # country code
      |[0]?  # or leading zero
    )?
    [789]\d{9}  # ten digits starting 7, 8 or 9
    |(\d[ -]?){10}\d  # or eleven digits with a separator
    $  # end of line
''', re.VERBOSE)
```

To complement the other answer, [Stop Writing Classes](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0).